# Yahoo OAuth malfunction with '&' character in the redirection URL

Tags: php, redirect, oauth, yahoo-api

Just finished coding an **OAuth Client** object with PHP, and it works just as expected for Facebook, Google, LinkedIn, Live and also for Yahoo with an abnormal glitch.

When a complex redirection URL is passed to Yahoo OAuth server for authorization, everything seems to work fine except Yahoo converts all the `&` characters in the URL to `&amp ;` character phrase causing me to make a `str_replace()` in the PHP code!

Original redirection URL for authorization:

> http://some.server.my/?Script=SignIn **&** OAuthProvider=Yahoo

Resulting redirection URL upon authorization action:

> http://some.server.my/?Script=SignIn **&amp ;** OAuthProvider=Yahoo

This causes the URL arguments *get lost in the dark!* Using a `str_replace()` in the PHP code does do the fix job, but am not happy with it.

Any idea why is it that this is happening and how to fix it (officially & in legal way)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you maybe urlencode() the redirection URL?

Comment: redirection url is already being sent in url encoded format using HTTP header redirect (Location). URL encoding the redirection URL is a requirement for OAuth protocol when authorizing (as far I understood).

A similar trouble has also been found (of course in my case) for Facebook with the slash '/' character.